# iTunes Connect TestFlight Not sending Invites

Tags: app-store-connect, testflight

Hello fellows smarter than I!

I am a technical user in iTunes connect for the project. I have Uploaded a build for beta testing and have invited two Internal Testers. It is telling me that they have been notified and I have also selected a build. Unfortunately however, no internal testers have received email notifications.

I've searched the web and haven't found any explanation that works. I have also noticed that answers weren't necessarily current, meaning at least 8 months old.

Any Help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer to this. My company was blocking the no_reply@apple.com 
Once I went into my 3rd tier email filter and whitelisted it I got sever invites.

Feel Free to comment and ask more should you run into the same issue as I!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to add private gmail account as a tester? 
I have had same issue few days ago, and just figured out that private accounts receive emails properly. Maybe company mail server block emails from "norepy" mail addresses?